# Twig template breaks when adding blocks

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

Here's the issue:

I have a custom content type for the contact page. Twig template: `page--node--9.html.twig`. When I add blocks to this template, e.g. `{{ page.contact-first }}`, it breaks. How can I display blocks on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: the naming of the regions need to use underscores, not dashes.

In `theme.info.yml`

```
regions:
  contact_first: 'Contact (First column)'
```

In the twig template:

```
{{ page.contact_first }}
```